# send keystroke to shell app?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am newbie in cocoa. I am working on a GUI for a shell app. I am using AMShellWrapper class, and it works fine.

The problem is that my shell app has a dialog requests a keystroke to continue. I'm pretty lost at this point. I've tried CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent but may not be the right way.

Anyone know how I can send a keystroke to a shell app that was initiated by my wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [`pty(4)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man4/pty.4.html) pseudo-terminal in which to run the application. This allows your application to be the "master" (think `Terminal.app`) which runs the "slave" program (think `bash(1)`) and provides mechanisms to control the slave.

This is a pretty involved area of Unix programming; I strongly recommend reading the source for the `pty.c` program in the sourcecode for the [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 2nd edition](http://www.apuebook.com/) book. (The source code would make a *lot* more sense if read with the companion chapter in the [book](http://www.powells.com/biblio/9780201433074).)

You could *probably* use the `pty.c` program unchanged and supply a 'driver' for it to drive your client program, which would simplify the task.